# Tweepy API- is it possible to only parse through a certain selection of tweets?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently making a tool that parses through a single users timeline on Tweepy. This the the for loop that does the job with a Cursor object.

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(self.api.user_timeline,screen_name=self.user, tweet_mode="extended",
                            include_rts=False,include_entities=True).items():
```

Parsing through a users timeline, however, can take a significant amount of time, especially when they have a lot of tweets. Im wondering if its possible to only parse through a specific part of the timeline, i.e. between the 20th and 40th tweets. I went through the Cursor documentation and failed to find anything.

I also tried this:
        for status in

```
tweepy.Cursor(self.api.user_timeline,screen_name=self.user, tweet_mode="extended",
                                    include_rts=True,include_entities=True).items():
            if r>=count and r<=max:
            Do operations here
```

But it didn't shorten the time it took.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is just a user-friendly wrapper around the actual paging interface. From the [docs](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/3.7.0/cursor_tutorial.html):

```
page = 1
while True:
    statuses = api.user_timeline(page=page)
    if statuses:
        for status in statuses:
            # process status here
            process_status(status)
    else:
        # All done
        break
    page += 1  # next page
```

With this, you can manually start page with an appropriate value, and stop it after a point.

I checked the source code for Cursor, and while it may be possible to inject a starting/ending page in there, this is probably easier.